# SFDX deploy ECONNRESET

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, mdapideploy

During a sfdx deploy, the CLI launched a random exception:

**ERROR running force:source:deploy:  read ECONNRESET
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure**

Someone has an idea of the problem? We tried deploy both source that mdapi format.

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: Try `sfdx update` to get the most recent version of the CLI - it might help

Comment: This is our configuration   sfdx-cli/7.33.2-045d48473e linux-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: I just ran the command and the most recent build is `7.36.0-b1c4e9c7c8`

Comment: I would also confirm the destination org has a live connection - use `sfdx force:org:list --all` to check

Comment: sorry, the new configuration is: sfdx-cli/7.36.0-b1c4e9c7c8 linux-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: `ECONNRESET` is a network error that's often just related to your local connection.

Comment: I don't have any problem with my network connection. Sometimes I use to get.