# Component conversion failed: This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

in VS code, while trying to deploy source to org, getting a weird error below:

Component conversion failed: This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
But I do have sfdx-project.json as below. WEIRD. Please help. thanks!

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "51.0"
}
```

Comment: I had that too and restarted VSCode and it went away.

Comment: ah..tried twice now :( no luck. extension pack version is v51.8.0

Comment: Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org is fine...issue pops only while trying to deploy source to org

Comment: Does it show the same error when you run from CLI?

Comment: Restarting VS fixes it for some time but error comes back randomly. Started happening this week. Must be a bug in the latest update.

Comment: @swetha - resolved after downgrading SF CLI integration to v55.3. New issue is retrieve from source for record type is not failing or erroring but the file is pretty blank. all the picklist values are missing

Comment: This keeps happening to me.  I am on CLI 7.208.10-178b759 and the latest VS Code CLI Integration v57.6.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise.  Its quite problematic.

Comment: I deleted my repo and brought it back down  from GitHub and was able to work.  However, after a reboot same error. I can do `sfdx deploy` just fine.  As mentioned in a comment below, this appears to be a Node error in the extension code.

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue arises when there's another vs code tab that it's already opened before the one with your project, so just close every other one tab and start with the one that holds the project, this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This was driving me insane!  Thanks for your tip. I closed all open tabs and, once reopened, the problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

I upgraded my VS Code and error went away.
Version: 1.74.3 (user setup)

Comment: I upgraded to same version but still facing the issue randomly. Restarting VS fixes it temporarily.

Comment: I had this problem with 1.74.3 version. It went away with 1.75 version.

Comment: I just reload window and it fixes the problem.

Comment: This keeps happening to me. I upgraded to VSCode 1.80.  I am on CLI 7.208.10-178b759 and the latest VS Code CLI Integration v57.6.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise. Its quite problematic.  Therefore I have started a bounty.

Comment: So this is related to a bug in the implementation with Node on Windows.

My sf.log has errors like in this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287761/sfdx-deploy-econnreset
This corresponds to similar issues folks have with node and filesystem operations on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696605/nodejs-in-windows-file-system-path-error-4058-enoent

Of course we need the SF team to fix this since we can't change their source code...

Comment: After upgrading everything and restarting multiple times, I went for the nuclear option.  I blew away my local repo and brought it back down from GitHub.  I am able to deploy again for the time being.

Answer (score 6):

Closing VS Code and reopening may not work because there seems to be caching.
To force the caching to be refreshed, open a new window, close the window with your project, and from the new window open the project.
Try to deploy your code again.

Comment: solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: How did you resolve?

Comment: @PraveenBehera What do you mean? My answer explains how I resolve it by clearing the cache.

Comment: @Gerard Sexton - I tried that. But after opening the new window now, my org is not connecting. I tried even restarting my PC. Do you know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In the VS code, Logout all the org using the below command and try again. It's helpful for you.

sfdx auth:logout --all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated the sfdx cli to v7.196.8 using powershell (when upgrading via a VS-Code terminal the upgrade progress seemed to stop after 120Mb).

Executing the logout command + restarting VS-code (v1.77.3, user setup) and re-authenticating the org worked for me.

Maybe multiple aliases for the same org were the problem... can't put a finger on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when there is some error in the code.

1. There might be some syntax error in **CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml**.
   The error in my case was, the mismatch in **labels** tags

Answer (score -1):

Close that VS Code window, then open it again. And authorize again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I had this happening constantly. Resolution was to update the Salesforce CLI. Latest CLI version does not seem to have any issues.

Comment: I updated my Salesforce CLI version to 7.196.7, and this issue seems to have been fixed.

Comment: updated to `sfdx-cli/7.197.8` and restarted VS Code